# Databricks Azure Notebooks csv file transformation

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a csv file with column name tags and it contains below values:

```
"ClusterId": "0206-090323-tkhhaz8a","pipeline_name":    "goal","BillingID": "Global Data Science Platform","Environment":    "DEV","description": "ingestion pipeline","**ClusterName**":    "965762","subproject_name": ingestion", "JobId":    "949239","Description": "Databricks injection","RunName":    "ADF_raw_curated","Creator": "24c1c23","Vendor":    "Databricks","adf_run_id": "3784","CostCenterIT": "917",    **"project_name"**: "goal","Owner": "XYZ","Account": "3456
```

I need to extract project_name and owner from above csv file tag column into a new column.Any suggestion how to do in pyspark.

Comment: This isn’t a csv, looks like bad json.  Why not just use json?  The trouble with using special custom formats is you now have to write a special custom format import routine.  It may be as simple as adding curly brackets to use json type methods, it may not, the point is if you use standard formats you can use standard imports.

Comment: so this json data is inside csv column.is there any way that i can pick one field from json data and create a df column

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this considering the data format is consistent.

```
df = spark.read.csv("dbfs:/FileStore/sample.csv")
display(df)

from pyspark.sql.functions import split
result = df.withColumn('Project_Name', split(df['_c14'], ':').getItem(1)).withColumn('Owner',split(df['_c15'], ':').getItem(1))
display(result)
```

[image: Solution]

However, the solution might depend on the usecase. You may also explore  regex  to extract the data.The Above solution is a basic one and does it's job.